# How to fix selected processor does not support `movw ' when trying to compile x264 for amrv6?

Tags: android, arm, codec, x264, armv6

I am getting following error when trying to compile x264 for android armv6.

common/arm/pixel-a.S: Assembler messages:
common/arm/pixel-a.S:1206: Error: selected processor does not support `movw ip,#:lower16:235963'
common/arm/pixel-a.S:1206: Error: selected processor does not support`movt ip,#:upper16:235963'
make: *** [common/arm/pixel-a.o] Error 1

my x264 script

./configure  --extra-ldflags='-march=armv6'   --extra-cflags='-march=armv6'  --cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi-  --enable-pic   --host=arm-linux

Comment: how did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

MOVW and MOVT are ARMv7 instructions, not ARMv6 instructions. Android only supports 2 ARM ABI's (ARMv5 and ARMv7). You will need to enable the ARMv7 ABI in your android.mk file by setting it:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

Documentation for these instructions can be found on the ARM website here:

[ARM Blog - how to load constants in ARM instructions](http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/251-how-to-load-constants-in-assembly-for-arm-architecture/)

Comment: movw/movt are v6T2 instructions